# nesting an <asp:net> literal tag with an html <div> vs nesting the <asp:net> literal in an <asp:panel>

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I have an existing code base and in some parts of the code the developer chose to surround the asp.net literal tag by an  asp.net panel tag. But in other parts of the code the developer chose to surround the asp.net literal tag with the html div tag. In both cases, the literal tag is a place holder for the errors message displays. I am not sure why one would be chosen over the other.

Below are the examples:

```
<div class="shadowContent">
                                    <div class="errorLabel" id="divErrorMsg" style="display:none">
                                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litError12" Text="Enter required fields." />
                                </div>
```

VS

```
                         <asp:panel runat="server" class="errorLabel" ID="pnlError1" Visible="false">
                            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="literal1" />
                         </asp:panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an asp.net panel if i have to modify the div on the server side otherwise i'd go with just a good ol div

Answer (score 0):

Is there a difference in the rendered HTML?  Ultimately a `Panel` just renders a `div` to the client.  If there's no need to refer to that `div` in a server-side context then using a plain `div` is probably going to result in minutely better performance, so perhaps the developer preferred that where possible.

However, if there was a need to refer to the `div` in server-side code (perhaps to make it visible or invisible) than a `Panel` would allow that.  As would just a server-side `div` control:

```
<div runat="server" ID="pnlError1">
```

There's little difference between these options, it's just a matter of what's easier to maintain and makes more sense in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `Panel` and sets its `Visible` property to `false`, then no `<div>` element is rendered at all. Conversely, if you use a `<div>` and set `style="display:none"`, then there will be a hidden `<div>` element, which you can make visible via client-side JavaScript.